# Query on Consistent 'sub' Field in id_token Across Different Apps with Apple OAuth Login

Tags: oauth, apple-login

I have a question about implementing Apple OAuth login in "multiple app_id" under the same developer account. We currently have an app, let's call it 'A', that already uses Apple OAuth. Now, we're planning to develop another app, which we'll refer to as 'B', and we aim to implement Apple login for this new app as well.

Our concern arises when a user who has previously logged in with app 'A' decides to log in with app 'B'. Specifically, we're looking for a way to identify the user consistently across both apps. We expect this identification to be performed by the 'sub' field in the id_token payload.

Is there a way to ensure that the 'sub' field in the id_token from a login in app 'A' will be identical to the 'sub' field in the id_token from a login in app 'B'? Can we utilize the App Group feature for this purpose?

We aim to use different App IDs for each app because the login page needs to display information relevant to app 'B', which is why using the same App ID for both apps is not an option for us.

I would greatly appreciate your guidance on this matter.

Thanks